# Bootstrap 4: How to change font size of text using media queries

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I added Bootstrap to my project, but it seems like the headings sizes are fixed and can't be changed. I'm trying to change the font size of my project, as my h1 and h2 text looks really big on mobile devices. For some reason, when I change the font-size of h1 and h2 tags, it seems to be ignored, and when I inspect it, they have lines through the code that adjust the font-size. I tried adding media queries too, but it is not working.

Code:

```
h1{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #E85A4F;
}

h2{
    font-size: 17.5px; 
}

p{
    font-size: 15px;    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
}
```

The odd thing is when I adjust the paragraph font-size, it works fine. Is there a way I can adjust the heading font size in the same way?

Comment: Seems to work as expected: https://codeply.com/p/mkJXCaqVEA

Comment: Try min and max-width both or use !important in font-size and check it's working or not.

Comment: !important works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The lines through the code mean, that the style is overwritten.

[image: Firefox debugger]

This image shows the font size of the `h1` of the code below. As you can see, there are multiple styles for `h1`. The one that is displayed at the top in the style panel (image above) gets applied. (This is the selector with the highest specifity, if there are multiple ones with the same specifity the last of the last stylesheet gets applied). On the right side you can see the file and the line where the style is applied.

To solve your problem you can:

1. Remove the code in the file and the line that is overwriting your headline style
2. Use a selector [with a higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), in this case for example `h1.headline`.
3. Add important to your style (`font-size: 30px!important;`), Note that this is the easiest but dirtiest solution

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
  h1{
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

/*
 a lot more css
 */
 
h1{
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="headline">Test</h1>
</div>
```